# Jsoup parse issue for paring script tag (with c tag) in Jsp file

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsoup, script-tag

I have a JSP file, from that file I need to get js file details from the script tag's src attribute. which is works fine for normal plain script tag(like given below)

```
<script src="/resources/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

am using the Jsoup libraries parse method with UTF-8 charset to parse the jsp file into html file

```
Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8");
```

From the Document (HTML document) am getting a collection of all the script tags with src attribute, in foreach loop am getting the src attributes details from the collection.

**Actual Script tag:**

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.min.js" />"></script>
```

**Jsoup 1.8.1 lib parsed output:**

```
<script src="<c:url value=" esources="" s="" query.min.js"=""></script>"&gt;
```

**Jsoup 1.12.1 lib parsed output:**

```
<script src="<c:url value=" resources js jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Expected output:**

```
"/resources/js/jquery.min.js"
```

**Actual output :**

```
"<c:url value="
```

Could anyone shed some light on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the JSoup parser doesn't like the inner quotes. I wouldn't say that this is a JSoup issue, since what your parsing isn't conforming to the HTML standard. In other words, I think JSoup is working as designed (the same can be said for the code formatting on SO).

I'm not sure if the JSP will work the same, but when I tried swapping out the inner double quotes for single quotes:

```
<script src="<c:url value'/resources/js/jquery.min.js' />"></script>
```

the parsing seems to work as you expected

```
<c:url value'/resources/js/jquery.min.js' />
```